# Can a peachfaced female lovebird and a female Fischer's lovebird get on?

Tags: behavior, birds, introducing-pets, parrots

I currently have a female lovebird and was thinking of getting her a friend. She is super tame, but since I work a lot I think it would be nice for her to have a friend while I'm away.

My breeder (because she only has Fischer's lovebirds available) suggested a Fischer's female lovebird and they can be friends.
I do not want to put them in separate cages as my bird is not caged. My current lovebird lives in my bathroom and has an outdoor extension where it eats and has fresh branches. Ideally, I want the other lovebird to join in this area. It's pretty big, so it's not like she can get territorial over the entire area... right?

Obviously I would introduce them slowly to begin with, but the overall goal would be for them to live together happily.

Is this possible? (Also, I do not want a male as I don't want mating and babies.)

Thanks :)

Comment: Hi Vanessa, welcome to Pets SE.

Comment: No matter how it will be, ask the breeder if she'll take the bird back  in the worst case. This will calm you and most times the option is not taken at the end :)